# ASP.NET RangeValidator's MaximumValue cannot convert to type Date

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, type-conversion, rangevalidator

I have a simple ASP.NET page, and in it I am trying to validate a date. The date picked must be greater than or equal to today's date.

I am getting an error which says "The value '26/04/2104 13:55:38' of the MaximumValue property of 'DateCheck' cannot be converted to type 'Date'" when I try to do this.

Here is the code in the aspx:

```
 Date: <asp:Calendar ID="txtDate" runat="server" BackColor="White" 
        BorderColor="#999999" CellPadding="4" DayNameFormat="Shortest" 
        Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black" Height="180px" 
        Width="200px">
        <DayHeaderStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="7pt" />
        <NextPrevStyle VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
        <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#808080" />
        <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#666666" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SelectorStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
        <TitleStyle BackColor="#999999" BorderColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" />
        <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
        <WeekendDayStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" />
    </asp:Calendar><br /><br />

    <asp:RangeValidator ID="DateCheck" runat="server" ErrorMessage="The date must be greater than or equal to current date" ControlToValidate="txtDate" 
    Display="Dynamic" Type="Date" ></asp:RangeValidator >
```

and here is the code behind file:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateCheck.MinimumValue = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        DateCheck.MaximumValue = DateTime.Now.AddYears(90).ToString();
    }
```

Can anyone help with solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess Easily you can achieve this through Javascript
My way is below

Firstly get todays Day like this

```
function validate_date(date_to_validate)
{
        var today = new Date();
        var dd = today.getDate();
        var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
        var vdate[]=date_to_validate.split('/');// Assuming Formated Date You will pass in mm/dd/yyyy
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

        if(dd<10) {
            dd='0'+dd
        } 
        if(mm<10) {
            mm='0'+mm
        } 
        today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;

        if(vdate[2]>yyyy+90 ||vdate[2]<yyyy)
        {
            return false;
        }else if(vdate[2]==yyyy && ( vdate[0]<mm ))
        {
           return false;
        }else if(vdate[2]==yyyy && (vdate[1]<dd))
        {
           return false;
        }
        else
        {
           return true;
        }
}
```

And this function return true for your min and max date condition else returns false...

I think Range validator Can Support string range ,integer range....
And you validating on server which will cost you extra request and response....
using client side validation you can do better

Comment: I hope This will Work For you

Answer (score 1):

Format of the MinimumValue and MaximumValue should be `yyyy/MM/dd`.
It is solved my problem.